# How to find bounds of multiple markers added to leafletLayer

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I am working with ngx-leaflet in an Angular 6 project, I draw multiple markers in my map and I want to center and zoom a leaflet map on multiple Markers

In the official doc you can do it by using [L.latlngBounds] and find other solutions using `L.featureGroup`

Since I am using ngx-leaflet, I don't have `L` variable, so I can't find `latlngBounds`and `featureGroup`

Here is my component:

```
import {latLng, tileLayer, polygon, marker, Icon, LatLngBounds} from 'leaflet';

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18})
    ],
    zoom: 5,
    center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909)
  };

  layers = [];
  fitBounds: LatLngBounds;
}

ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
        this.layers.push(this.locations[i].y, this.locations[i].x].setIcon(
            new Icon({
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [13, 41],
                iconUrl: 'assets/icons/marker-icon.png',
                shadowUrl: 'assets/icons/marker-shadow.png'
        })));
    }
}

}
```

And my template:

```
<div id="map" leaflet
             [leafletOptions]="options"
             [leafletLayers]="layers"
             [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds">
        </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import it

If you want to use `featureGroup()`:

```
import {featureGroup, latLng, tileLayer, polygon, marker, Icon, LatLngBounds} from 'leaflet';


const marker1 = marker([51.5, -0.09]);
const marker2 = marker([50.5, -0.09]);

const group = featureGroup([marker1, marker2]);

group.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

EDIT: I overlooked the fact your are using ngx

As you are using ngx-leaflet, you can get the map object in the `leafletMapReady` [event](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#leafletmapready-map)

Modify your directive:

```
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet 
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

Modify your `CustomComponent` (adapt this example with the content of your ngOnInit method):

```
onMapReady(map: Map) {
    const marker1 = marker([51.5, -0.09]);
    const marker2 = marker([50, -0.09]);

    const group = featureGroup([marker1, marker2]);

    group.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
 }
```

Comment: How have u used ```map``` ?

Comment: thanks a lot, although it was a quick answer but it did everything